# acrobat pro - text field - checking for invalid values

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I'm trying to check the value of a text field, if the text box contains certain words, it will alert the user of the invalid value. I tried the following, but not working.

```
var nstr = event.value;
if(nstr = "SGP")
    app.alert("Not a valid form");
var nstr = event.value;
if(nstr = "CGT")
    app.alert("Not a valid form");
var nstr = event.value;
if(nstr = "PTS")
    app.alert("Not a valid form");
```

I'm using Adobe Acrobat Pro, i put the script in Text Field Properties:Validate:Run custom validation script.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(nstr = "SGP")
```

becomes

```
if(nstr == "SGP")
```

and so on..

Also, you don't need to assign event.value to nstr before each condition.

This switch statement would achieve the same end result with less code repetition:

```
switch(event.value) {
    case 'SGP':
    case 'CGT':
    case 'PTS':
       app.alert("Not a valid form");
}
```

Comment: thanks! that worked, but one more thing. I want to add event.rc = false, do I add it to the end or under app.alert?